# UI automation using python and appium - Unable to launch WebDriverAgent

Tags: python, ios, appium, ui-automation, iphone7plus

I am trying to open and login to the yelp app on an Iphone 7 plus using appium and python. Here is the code that I have

```
device_name = "iPhone 7 Plus"
udid = "XXXXXX"

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities={
        'bundleId': "com.yelp.yelpiphone",
        'platformName': 'iOS',
        'deviceName': device_name,
        'udid': udid,
        'automationName': 'XCUITest',
        'platformVersion': '11.1'
    }
)
```

But the app does not open and I get the following error on the Appium server

```
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". 
Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. 
Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you visit the page you get in [stacktrace](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md) you will find that most often the problem is related to *not signed* or *incorrectly signed* app.

This is the problem you most likely won't face running on emulator, so if you still want to run on real device follow the [instructions](https://github.com/imurchie/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/isaac-rs/docs/real-device-config.md#basic-manual-configuration) to fix this.

And if you want to run on real devices you must provide `xcodeConfigFile` capability, check [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md#basic-automatic-configuration) what to include there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to get it resolved , i assume you have correct signing id

1) go to WebdriverAgentLib>Signing in section , uncheck and check **Automatic Signin** again
select the correct dev id in drop down

2) go to WebdriverAgentRunner>Signing in Section, uncheck and check **Automatic Signin** again
select the correct dev id in drop down

3)go to Keychain access and remove any expired certificate

4)build again